# Where to place loader.conf on an EFI system partition with the GRUB bootloader?

Tags: freebsd, nvme

I'm attempting to alias /dev/nvmeX as /dev/nvdX on bootup through the following guide: https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=nvd

I would like to know where the loader.conf file with the following contents are supposed to be placed to alias /dev/nvme0 as /dev/nvd0 on bootup:

```
nvme_load="YES"
nvd_load="YES"
```

loader.conf manpage: https://man.archlinux.org/man/loader.conf.5

The loader.conf manpage mentions that,

> systemd-boot(7) will read ESP/loader/loader.conf...

I'm aware that "ESP" refers to an EFI system partition. So on an EFI system partition with the GRUB bootloader, would the proper loader.conf placement be something like /boot/loader/loader.conf, /boot/efi/loader/loader.conf, or /loader/loader.conf ?

Additional question: Is loader.conf specific to an ESP system partition and doesn't work through a BIOS/MBR system partition?

I've attempted this on a BIOS/MBR system partition using the suggested placements above with no success.

Comment: Is this an XY problem? Why do you need this?

Comment: This was an XY problem. Hopefully this re-format helps. I need this to be able to alias /dev/nvme0 as /dev/nvd0 on bootup.

Comment: Systemd (Linux) loader.conf seems unlikely to be similar to FreeBSD loader.conf?

Comment: I’m still not sure why you need this or what your goal is. Do you want to be able to boot select between arch and FreeBSD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the ESP is mounted at `/boot/efi`, the Arch `loader.conf` should be placed at `/boot/EFI/loader/loader.conf`.

If the ESP is mounted at `/boot`, then it should be at `/boot/loader/loader.conf` respectively.

And if you view the ESP filesystem through the GRUB prompt or any other mechanism that will focus on only one filesystem at a time, it should be at `/loader/loader.conf`. In other words, the man page is specifying the `loader.conf` location as relative to the mount point/root directory of the ESP filesystem.

The `loader.conf` described by Arch's man page refers to the configuration file of `systemd-boot`, which is an UEFI-only bootloader. It has no relation to FreeBSD's bootloader and its `loader.conf` file, although it uses the same filename. Although `systemd-boot` can boot Windows and MacOS in addition to Linux, it doesn't seem to directly support booting FreeBSD.

On a system that uses legacy BIOS, you cannot use the `systemd-boot` bootloader, and the version of GRUB that supports BIOS (=GRUB architecture code `i386-pc`) does not use `loader.conf` at all by default.